# Текст смещается в зависимости от длины текста, как это исправить

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas

Текст в canvas начинается не с начала экрана и смещается, если увеличить длину текста, выходит за пределы текстового поля, если текст длинный. Как это можно исправить?

```
from tkinter import *
root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(width=1024, height=768)
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, bg='white')
canvas1.create_text(240,40,fill="darkblue",font="Times 20 italic bold",   text="ddddddd")
canvas1.create_text(240,70,fill="darkblue",font="Times 20 italic bold",   text="ddddddddddddddddd")
canvas1.create_text(240,100,fill="darkblue",font="Times 20 italic bold",   text="dddddddddddddddddddddddddddd")
canvas1.create_text(240,130,fill="darkblue",font="Times 20 italic bold",   text="dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd")
canvas1.place(x=0, y=0, height=300, width=970)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По умолчанию координаты указывают на середину текста, изменить поведение можно с помощью параметра `anchor` с соответствующим [значением](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/anchors.html).

Максимальная ширина задается с помощью `width`.

Подробнее [тут](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_text.html) (на английском).

```py
text = (
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu "
    "venenatis ex. Donec odio neque, porta sed mattis bibendum, "
    "pellentesque a enim. Donec posuere semper est vitae aliquet. Donec "
    "laoreet nisl eget erat pretium, ac rutrum orci imperdiet. Donec quis "
    "luctus neque. Cras risus arcu, luctus ac sapien a, auctor mollis "
    "lorem. In sit amet purus id neque pharetra vestibulum.")
canvas1.create_text(
    10, 10,
    fill="darkblue",
    font="Times 20 italic bold",
    anchor=tk.NW,
    width=500,
    text=text)
```